# Can't access class field in another class

Tags: c#

```
public class Vector
    {
        public int[] row = new int[2];
        public Vector(int x, int y)
        {
            this.row[0] = x;
            this.row[1] = y;
        }
        public int[] Row
        {
            get
            {
                return row;
            }
        }
    }
public class Matrix<Vector>
    {
        public Vector[] rows = new Vector[2];
        public Matrix(Vector v1, Vector v2){
            this.rows[0] = v1;
            this.rows[1] = v2;
        }
        public void Transform()
        {
            foreach (Vector v in rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(v.row[0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting  'Vector' does not contain a definition for 'row' and I have no idea why. It's set to public and I'm iterating over vector objects. What am I doing wrong here?

This is my first time using c#, coming from python so please don't mind the code if it doesn't make sense. Just toying with classes and syntax

Comment: Because you're requesting a generic parameter for `Matrix` and naming it `Vector`. This means that you're effectively defining a new type named `Vector` for the class. What is your intention with `Matrix`?

Comment: C# is case-sensitive. You're invoking `row` but the property is `Row`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney His field `row` is public too.

Comment: @john, yeah, just noticed that. I was about to delete my comment but I'll leave it for completeness.

Comment: That said, the field SHOULD be private. If you have it exposed via a read-only property then making it public doesn't make sense.

Comment: @john oh so this is the culprit? Is it possible to do what I want with that generic parameter? Not sure if I understand how they work

Comment: I just re-read @john's first comment and realised what he meant.  It really doesn't make sense that `Matrix` is generic to begin with.  Just change `Matrix<Vector>` to `Matrix` and it will work. Unless you wanted a `Matrix` to be able to work with types other than the `Vector` class you defined, making it generic doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can [read the docs on generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/introduction-to-generics) but as jmcilhinney says, I don't think you want generics in this case.

Answer (score 3):

here as you have written in your question,

```
public class Matrix<Vector>
```

means, your class `Matrix` is generic, and whatever type you will pass while creating an instance of `Matrix`, code of this class will take that type as `Vector` .

**Note that your class `Vector` is total different type than the type `Vector` in `Matrix` class.**

For ex.

if your create an object of matrix like this,

```
Matrix<string> m = new Matrix<string> ("amit", "maheshwari");
```

this will be valid and for this instacne of `Matrix`, `Vector` will be string. and yes `string` does not contain a definition for 'row' and so does `Vecotr`.

So, maybe you are misusing this class.

Or if you have created this class by your self and you want to perform what you have shown in question, there is no need to make this class generic.

```
public class Matrix
{
    //so now this array of vector will be of class Vector
    public Vector[] rows = new Vector[2];
    public Matrix(Vector v1, Vector v2){
        this.rows[0] = v1;
        this.rows[1] = v2;
    }
    public void Transform()
    {
        foreach (Vector v in rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v.row[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Matrix<TVector> where TVector : Vector
{
    public TVector[] rows = new TVector[2];
    public Matrix(TVector v1, TVector v2)
    {
        this.rows[0] = v1;
        this.rows[1] = v2;
    }
    public void Transform()
    {
        foreach (TVector v in rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v.row[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for John and other friends for reply quick answer. you must use TVector.

Comment: But if OP only has, and will only ever have, one type of Vector with no derived types, he doesn't need generics at all.

Comment: @john exactly. I agree with you